# How to manipulate an object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a laravel query as the one below:

```
$campaign = Campaign::with(array('tracks.flights' => function($q) use ($dates)
            {
                $q->whereRaw("flights.start_date  BETWEEN '". $dates['start']."' AND '".$dates['end']."'")->orderBy('start_date')
                ->with('asset')
                ->with('comments');
            }
        ))
        ->with('tracks.group')
        ->with('tracks.media')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->find($id);
```

I am very new to laravel and right now the response from this query returns all the data required including the comments with the comments attributes from the DB.

What i want to achieve is manipulate the comments object so it includes the user name from the users table as the comments table has the user_id only as an attribute.

How can I achieve this? I am very new to laravel.

Comment: New to PHP too, I am not very sure how PHP handles this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Comment` model must have a relationship with the `User` model, such as:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Now when you are iterating comments you are able to do `$comment->user->name` or in your case it will be something like this:

```
@if(!$campaign->tracks->flights->isEmpty())
    @foreach($campaign->tracks->flights as $flight)
        @if(!$flight->comments->isEmpty())
            @foreach($flight->comments as $comment)
                {!! $comment->user->name !!}
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Once you can do this, next step is to understand eager load with eloquent.